# Error handler fails to go to appropriate line on second error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am trying to log errors that occur when I move data from an Excel file to a MS Project file.

When the code encounters the first UniqueID that does not match, it logs the UniqueID to the listbox as intended.

If a second error is encountered I get

> "Argument value not valid"

It is like it forgets about the `On Error GoTo 100`. The Excel file opens and if there are no error it updates as desired.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton91_Click()

'open progress data file
    
    Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    myxl.Workbooks.Open TextBox110.Value
    
    Set wb = activeworkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
25
        If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "False" Then
        
            If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "False" Then
                
                On Error GoTo 100
                
                ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value).Number7 = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
                ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value).Number6 = ws.Cells(i, 17).Value
                
                If CheckBox34.Value = True Then
                    ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value).Duration = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value * 480
                End If

            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Unload Me
    
    Exit Sub
100
    ListBox20.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
    GoTo 25
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to reset the error handler object, to do that, replace `GoTo 25` with `Resume 25`.

Comment: "Resume XXX" is the only safe way to exit from an error handler I think.  See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm#:~:text=Moreover%2C%20Resume%20is%20the%20only%20way%2C%20aside%20from%20exiting%20the%20procedure%2C%20to%20get%20out%20of%20an%20error%20handling%20block.